# Num lock keeps changing when moving the cursor between VMware and desktop

Tags: vmware-player

I don't know why when pointing the mouse over VMware window Num Lock goes off. Then it goes on when moving it back to the real desktop. Is there any way to stop that. It's annoying.

Comment: Just switch it on the one that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Turn Num Lock on in the VM and that problem will stop

Comment: The NumLock states are independent in the host machine and VM - so just press the NumLock key until you have the desired result in both.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable that small window, but you can set Num Lock state to be the same on the VM and your host. Then, no notification will occur when switching VM and host.
For instance, my Num Lock is *On* because I often use numerical keyboard.

*Explanation*: when using VM, there are **three** different Num Lock states: one from VM BIOS, one from VM OS and one from the host. VM Windows remembers last Num Lock state.

```
VM BIOS: 
  Main / Keyboard Configuration:
```

[image: VM BIOS setup]

*Behavior:* for example, if you set BIOS default state to **ON**, and last state in Windows was **ON**, when VM is booting, Num Lock is changing from  *ON* to *OFF* when Windows starts, and then to *ON* again when Windows finishes booting.